# azure maps language support

Tags: rest, azure, azure-maps

When I make an API request for a single address with Swedish letters I get a correct answer but if the same address is part of a batch request all the special characters are substituted for unicode and I get no hit. I've tried URL Encode the queries in the batch but that makes no difference.
This works:

```
/search/address/json?query=Långsjövägen, 13554 Tyresö&api-version=1.0&subscription-key=123
```

But a post like this doesn't:

```
{ "queries":
  [
    "?query=Långsjövägen, 13554 Tyresö",
  ]
}
```

I can get the batch respons and all works fine except that the unicode messes up the search.
How can I make batch request with special characters?

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround.

Try:

```
{ "queries":
  [
    "?query=Langsjovagen, 13554 Tyreso",
  ]
}
```

I just tried it and it gave back the right results. So, just use "a" in place of "å" and so on.

That'll probably get you unblocked until it gets fixed on their side.

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode your queries to ensure that special characters don't have any issues. Here are the different methods to use for different languages:

- JavaScript: encodeURIComponent(query)
- C#/VB: Uri.EscapeDataString(query)
- Java: URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8")
- Python:

  import urllib.parse

  urllib.parse.quote(query)

Then add the encoded query value into your URL.